# How to retrieve data from a form (POST) on a twig without flush them

Tags: forms, symfony, parameters, twig

I try with a simple controller and a form to send the different parameter to another page and retrieve them on this page, I don't want to flush them yet in the database, I want first apply this Logi : You got a form with action and method then on the action page you just have to retrieve your data like this $_POST['data'] or $_GET['data']. I am new on Symfony and I just want to replicate this logic with my data.

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Brasser;
use App\Form\BrasserType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class BrasserController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/brasser", name="brasser")
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $biere = new Brasser();
        $form  = $this->createForm(BrasserType::class, $biere, [
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('panier'),
        ]);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $form->getData();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('panier');
        }

        return $this->render('brasser/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'BrasserController',
            'brasser'         => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/panier", name="panier")
     */
    public function panier()
    {
        $panier = 'Votre sélection de bière';

        return $this->render('brasser/panier.html.twig', [
            'panier' => $panier,
        ]);
    }
}
```

My template :

```
   {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
   {% block body %}
   {{ panier }}
    <p><a href="{{ path('accueil') }}">Retour accueil</a></p>
   {% endblock %}
```

BrasserType :

```
 <?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Brasser;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class BrasserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('orge', CheckboxType::class)
            ->add('houblon', CheckboxType::class)
            ->add('epice', CheckboxType::class)
            ->add('Valider', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class'=> Brasser::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I look with a dump into the request I have the data but into the request parameters and I can't get them to use them.

```
array:3 [▼
  "panier" => "Votre sélection de bière"
  "essai" => null
  "app" => Symfony\Bridge\Twig\AppVariable {#731 ▼
    -tokenStorage: Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\UsageTrackingTokenStorage {#150 ▶}
    -requestStack: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack {#106 ▼
      -requests: array:1 [▼
        0 => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request {#45 ▼
          +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#89 ▶}
          +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#96 ▼
            #parameters: array:1 [▼
              "brasser" => array:5 [▼
                "orge" => "1"
                "houblon" => "1"
                "epice" => "1"
                "Valider" => ""
                "_token" => "8krrCjCTfKsG8UkaDbhRNKXQjrD63cxJWKog4pR46Ws"
              ]
            ]
          }
```

Here it is what $form->getData() contains before the redirectRoute.

```
object(App\Entity\Brasser)#739 (4) {
  ["id":"App\Entity\Brasser":private]=>
  NULL
  ["orge":"App\Entity\Brasser":private]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  ["houblon":"App\Entity\Brasser":private]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["epice":"App\Entity\Brasser":private]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your form and add the code of BrasserType.php ?

Comment: Hello Dhia, yes I just edit it

Comment: Do u have getters and setters on your Brasser.php entity ?

Comment: Yes I did my entity with the Doctrine command, so they all have setter and getter methods in the entity

Comment: There is no code given that writes anything to the database, so everything should be fine. Can you clarify your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass informationsyou Can add it to parameters in your function to redirect like this :

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('panier', ['panier' => $form->getData()]);
```

Then you can recover your data in your next controller :

```php
function panier(Request $request) {

  $panier = $request->request->get('panier');

   return $this->render('brasser/panier.html.twig', [
     'panier' => $panier
   ]);
}
```

Comment: Hello Rémi, thank you very much for your answer, can I use getData to retrieve my array of data in my controller view.     /**
     * @Route("/panier", name="panier")
     */
    public function panier(Request $request)
    {
        $panier='Votre sélection de bière';
        $mydata = $request->request->get('Hello');
        return $this->render('brasser/panier.html.twig',[
            'panier'=>$panier,
            'essai'=>$mydata
        ]);
    }

Comment: I mean all the data contained in the aray in one time not just field by field ?

Comment: Instead of passing ['panier' => $form->getData()] in parameters, try to pass you complete form ['form' => $form]. So, you should be able to get your data in your function 'panier' like this : $request->request->get('form')->getData();

Comment: Hello, thank you very much everybody for your time and help. Finally I solved the issue with your tips Rémi, it wass a name's error in my array, I didn't target the rigth array.